# PHP preg_match_all get fetch all images to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, image, preg-match-all

Pretty much self explanatory...

Here is my code :

```
$html=<<<EOF

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> 
<img  alt="title" height="120" width="50" src="title.jpg" />
<img  alt=Footer src=footer.bmp height=30 width=47     />
<br>
<img  alt=Footer  height=10 src='square.jpeg' width=10     />
<div id="test"><img      longdesc="" width=100 src="transparent.png" height=43></div>
EOF;
```

preg_match_all("//",$html,$images);

I want to be able to return all image files to an array with preg_match_all (or any other magic :)

I'm expecting to get an array with all pictures so `var_dump($images);` would be:

```
smiley.gif
title.jpg
footer.bmp
square.jpeg
transparent.png
```

Comment: preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>/s', $html, $images); var_dump($images[2]);

Comment: Working ! :) How can I take all options (double quotes or single quotes or nothing after src=) ? for example : <img src='1.jpg' <img src="1.jpg" <img src=1.jpg

Comment: preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)src=("|\'|)(.*?)("|\'| )(.*?)>/s', $html, $images);
var_dump($images[3]);

Comment: ok so I got now small tweak " or ' but how can I say OR NOTHING?? preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)src=["|\'](.*?)["|\'](.*?)>/s',$html,$images);

Comment: PERFECT MAN! THANK YOU SO MUCH! You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*?)src=("|\'|)(.*?)("|\'| )(.*?)>/s', $html, $images);
var_dump($images[3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), vor example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlstring);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($elements as $element) {
 print $element->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Question is : What is FASTER ? :)

Comment: I will do a speed test now to compare between both methods ! Thanks !

Comment: try it :-) `$start = microtime(true);

//Your Script Content here

$end = microtime(true);
$time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);

echo 'This page loaded in ', $time, ' seconds'; `

Comment: Opps! preg_match_all is much more FASTER ! :-)